Extension of a module $M$ with $\mathbb Z_{(p)}$ structure to a module with $\mathbb Q$ structure
Let $R$ be a ring and $M$ an $R$-module. For each $r \in R$ we define
$T_r^R: M \to M$ as $v \mapsto rv$.
Let $A$ be a subring of the ring $B$, if $M$ is an $A$-module, we say that the structure of $A$-module extends to the structure of $B$-module if $M$ has the structure of $B$-module and for all $r \in A$ we have $T_r^A = T_r^B$
So I am required to prove this. Let $p$ be a prime number
$$\mathbb{Z}_{(p)} = \bigg\{\frac{a}{b}: \gcd(a,b) = 1 \text{ and } p \text{ doesn't divide b}\bigg\} $$
Then $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ is a subring of the rationals and if M is a $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$-module such that it extends to a $\mathbb Q$-module then the function $T_p^{\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}}$ is invertible.
I've already shown that $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ is a subring of the rationals, and i've shown that $T_p^{\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}}$ is injective. The argument is the following.
let $v,v' \in M$ be such that $T_p^{\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}}(v) = T_p^{\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}}(v')$
then using   $T_p^{\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}} = T_p^{\mathbb{Q}}$ we have
$T_p^{\mathbb{Q}}(v) = T_p^{\mathbb{Q}}(v')$ so $pv = pv'$ and since we are working with rational scalars we can divide by $p$ and get $v = v'$.
What I'm having trouble is proving that the function $T_p^{\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}}$ is surjective, my idea is to let $v \in M$, then the element $v' = \frac{1}{p} v$ is such that $T_p^{\mathbb Q} (v') = v $ but the problem is that $v'$ is not in $M$, but in the extension so it doesn't make sense to evaluate $T_p^{\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}}(v')$. And that's where i'm stuck so any help is appreciated.

Actually, it makes perfect sense to evaluate $T_p^{\mathbb{Z_{(p)}}}(v')$. Recall the definition of extension that you wrote above. The set $M$ itself remains unchanged, it is exactly the same abelian group. The only change is that we just allow multiplying by more scalars, but the result will still be an element in the same set $M$. In particular, your element $v'$ is an element in $M$, and so in the domain of $T_p^{\mathbb{Z_{(p)}}}$.
Anyway, instead of checking that the function is injective and surjective, you can just construct an inverse. Note that in general $T_r^R\circ T_s^R=T_{rs}^R$, and $T_1^R=\text{id}_M$, this is immediate. So, since $p$ is invertible in $\mathbb{Q}$, it should be clear what the inverse function should be.
